# What other purposes does isalpha() do in my program?

Tags: c

I just wrote this little program instructed by my practice book to check if two words entered by user are anagrams, and it executed perfectly.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,
        same = 1,
        letter[26] = {0};

    char C;

    printf("Enter your first word:");
    while((C = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if(isalpha(C));
        letter[toupper(C) - 'A']++;

    }

    printf("Enter second word: ");

    while((C = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if(isalpha(C));
        letter[toupper(C) - 'A']--;


    }

    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(letter[i] != 0)
        same = 0;
        break;
    }

    if(same)
    {
    printf("The letters are the same");
    return 0;
    }

    printf("The letters are not the same");
    return 0;
}
```

During the test, I tried to remove both `isalpha()` functions for their sole purposes are to test whether the inputs are characters, which is not entirely necessary.

```
printf("Enter your first word:");
    while((C = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        letter[toupper(C) - 'A']++;

    }

    printf("Enter second word: ");

    while((C = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        letter[toupper(C) - 'A']--;
```

However, some logical error started to occur. I entered two different characters and it said the result were the same, and it makes wonder what role `isalpha()` plays in this program besides checking whether the inputs are characters. I'd be grateful if you can answer me, thank you.

Comment: Without the semicolon(s) mentioned by @ArdentCoder, the `isalpha` calls are checking that your input characters are letters; if any is not then, *without* those checks, the lines using `letter[toupper(C) - 'A']` would be referencing array elements out of bounds.

Comment: Re "*However, some logical error started to occur.*", Please provide a minimal, runable demonstration of the problem (including inputs, of course!)

Comment: **Lesson** -- if you compile with *warnings enabled*, e.g. gcc/clang `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` or `/W3` for VS, the compiler will point the problem areas of your code out to you -- including the line number on which they occur, e.g. `"15:23: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body] if(isalpha(C));"` and the same warning for line:column `24:23`. Always compile with *warnings enabled* and do not accept code until it compiles **without warning**.

Comment: If you don't have better platform ideas, please just try out your code on gdbonline.com and copy the link *as well as the code* into the question. That way you'll ensure that the code compiles and runs, and you can focus on problems.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the situation where someone provides the word `isn't`. `toupper(C) - 'A'` expects `C` to be a letter, and the `isalpha` check causes the `'` to be ignored.

---

Note that the test is ineffective the way you wrote it because of the misplaced semi-colon.

```
if(isalpha(C));
letter[toupper(C) - 'A']++;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(isalpha(C)) { }
letter[toupper(C) - 'A']++;
```

but you want

```
if(isalpha(C)) {
    letter[toupper(C) - 'A']++;
}
```

or

```
if(isalpha(C))
    letter[toupper(C) - 'A']++;
```

---

Another error later in your code invalidates your check to see if all the counts are zero.

```
if(letter[i] != 0)
same = 0;
break;
```

means

```
if(letter[i] != 0) {
    same = 0;
}

break;
```

You want

```
if(letter[i] != 0) {
    same = 0;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned because of `;` after `if(isalpha(C))` , this function is doing nothing in your code.

and also here in this loop

```
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(letter[i] != 0)
        same = 0;
        break;
    }
```

you are missing braces , which means if this`if(letter[0]!=0)` is true ,`same` will become `0` ,and if not `same` will remain `1`, then `break;` will executed and loop will end. which means for many possible cases your code will be wrong you should add `{}`.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (letter[i] != 0)
        {
            same = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
```